# MailChimp API V3 errors list

Tags: mailchimp

I can't find a complete list the errors that the API `title` and `details` can return in case of failure. Reading the documentation : http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/ they only talk about status code error and not about message.

In my case I use it to subscribe users to a list but the `400` error status is thrown for a lot of purpose, like "Member exists" or "Invalid Resource" (in case of a blank email address). I need to translate some error message so a complete list of "possible" ones would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error glossary you list does contain all status codes and titles for errors returned by the API as far as I know. It doesn't contain all possible messages, but I don't think that list is available anywhere.

Comment: You're right but looking at the old API documentation we had some status code with more "meaning" https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/exceptions.field.php like `214` for a user already exists. It was easy to change the output for the user. Now the `400` is thrown for a lot of reason and we can only rely on the title message that is only in english...

Comment: You'll want to talk to support about that. There's presently no other list of errors available that I've seen. For user exists, you might try using PUT instead to do an add-or-update operation.

Comment: The 1.3 list of errors above now redirects to the 3.0 documentation, but you can still access it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130209144951/https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/exceptions.field.php